# What is alternate of like operator with group_concate in spark sql?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe, sql-like

In mysql we use can use `like` operator on `group_concat`  e.g

```
select case when group_concat(color) like '%red%' then 1 else 0 end;
```

but it does not work in spark sql as i used `collect_set` instead of `group_concat` . 
it shows exception that mismatch of data types.

Answer (score 0):

Although you *can* do that in MySQL, the better solution is:

```
select max(color = 'red')
```

I think the following should work in Spark:

```
select max(case when color = 'red' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Note:  This assumes that you are looking only for the color red.  If you are looking for IndianRed, then use `like`.

Comment: actually i am using collect_set instead of group_concat and it gives the same result but the thing is i want to apply case statement on this result set e.t

Comment: actually i am using collect_set instead of group_concat and it gives the same result but the thing is i want to apply case statement on this result set e.d

select case when collect_set(color) like 'red' then 1 else 0 end.
but it gives error of data type mismatch.

Comment: @Badar . . . The code in my answer uses neither `group_concat()` nor `collect_set()`, so I don't understand your comments.